# Can't create a HTTPS listener for my Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I'm using AWS for hosting some of my APIs through a Load Balancer, and using the DNS Name they gave me. When trying to add a HTTPS listener, I need to request a SSL certificate, which I try with the certificate manager, but I can't request it because the domain is from Amazon. What can I do to have my API served through HTTPS in AWS?

Comment: You need to set up your own domain (maybe in Route53?) so you can get a certificate.  Then set the A record for the load balancer under that domain to be an ALIAS of the load balancer's amazon DNS name.

Comment: you need an SSL certificate, you can create your own using openssl for your test environment and import it in the certificate manager but when accessing the DN it will show us not trusted, for your prod environment you can either follow @erik258 suggestion or buy a domain name from a certified domain provider(e.g., godaddy)